# Is there an R function for pulling data(it is actually not database, the data is unstructured that has sentences) from 2 excel files

Tags: r

There are 2 excel files. Each excel file has different sheets. Lets say, there are 2 excel files in my working directory. File1 and File2. 
File1 has 4 sheets and File2 has 5 sheets. All the sheet names have different names.

Example:
File1(Price, Planning, contract, delivery)
File2(CND, Discount, Installation, Price, Affidavit)

Now i need to extract the above data in R. I Need to have finally 2 files in R with object name coming as File names and also Sheet name getting reflected in the data.

So for example. My final R files should be like

1) "File1" that has all the data(from all the 5 sheets) from Excel File1 
2) "File2" that has all the data(from all the 4 sheets) from Excel File2

Can we have something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use package `openxlsx` to open the Excel files. To load all sheets into a structure you could do:

```
library(openxlsx)

sheetNames = names(loadWorkbook("Book1.xlsx"))
File_1 = lapply(sheetNames, function(x){read.xlsx("Book1.xlsx",sheet = x)})
names(File_1) = sheetNames
```

This will read the sheet names from the 'Book1.xlsx' file and then proceed to read all data into `File_1`. The last line will add the sheets' name to each element in the list.

The structure you get is a list. For example:

```
> File_1
$Sheet1
  1 2
1 3 4

$Sheet2
  1 2
1 1 2
2 1 2
```

#### Edit:

If you want to read all Excel files and store them in the same structure do:

```
library(openxlsx)
filenames = list.files(pattern = "\\.xlsx$")

fullData = lapply(filenames, function(fil){
  sheetNames = names(loadWorkbook(fil))
  File_data = lapply(sheetNames, function(x){read.xlsx(fil,sheet = x)})
  names(File_data) = sheetNames
  File_data
})

names(fullData) = filenames
```

Explanation:

`lapply` will loop over all filenames that end in `.xlsx` and for each one:

- read each workbook's sheet names
- load the sheet data
- add the sheet name

And after reading all files, the name of each file is added to the result.

Result (for two files created for this):

```
> fullData
$Book1.xlsx
$Book1.xlsx$Sheet1
  1 2
1 3 4

$Book1.xlsx$Sheet2
  1 2
1 1 2
2 1 2


$Book2.xlsx
$Book2.xlsx$Income
  11 22 55 77
1 33 44 66 88

$Book2.xlsx$Expenses
  3 55
1 3 55
2 3 55
```

Comment: Thanks, But loadworkbook is getting executed. Could not find the function. What package should I install?

Comment: Perfect Thanks. But Since there are multiple files, I tried the below code to read all files.                                                                                  
       filenames<-list.files()                                                                                                  
       for (i in 1:length(filenames)) 
       {
       sheetNames = names(loadWorkbook[i])
       names(File_1) = sheetNames                                                                                 
       }

Comment: @Vinay added the package to open excel files.

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot. But is there a way to export it all in one go. Because the full data is in list. It has different rows and columns. Cannot we export it in single short?

Comment: Also my directory has both xlsx and xls formats. I tried with list.files().But not able to get it

Comment: openxlsx does not work for xls files. And yes, the data will be in a list, but if you want a data frame, all tables must have the same columns (in name) before you rbind. You could rbind with `do.call(fullData, rbind)`

Comment: since these have different rows and columns, Cannot we export these data frames in different sheets in excel?

Comment: @Vinay do you want to read from Excel (import to R) or write to Excel (export)?

Comment: Both ways. The challenge is I have 300 excel files with multiple sheets. The data is unstructured actually that is there was written statements in it and not a proper data format(rows and columns). So i need to read them into R first.  Once I have rows and columns generated, i need to export them into Excel in one single file(incase if not single file). At least 4 to 5 files where I can get all information that are present in multiple sheets across muliple excels

Comment: Also, while exporting from Excel to R, I have some sentences with Bold format in excel, Can this bold be generated while importing as well? Hope you got my point

Comment: @ Schifini, while extracting can we make headers common like (x1, x2, x3 and so on). Because, right now only first rows is coming as headers

Comment: @Vinay xlsx package can read and write cell styles if I'm not mistaken. [Here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/r-xlsx-package-a-quick-start-guide-to-manipulate-excel-files-in-r) is a guide that could help you. Setting common headers can be done with `colnames(df) = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3']`. Reading 300 files into R and then export back to Excel may be difficult but not impossible. Start with two and then try to scale up.

Comment: Thanks Schifini, I was using the the below code to get the data. 
    >library(openxlsx)
    >filenames = list.files(pattern = "\\.xlsx$")
    >fullData = lapply(filenames, function(fil){
     sheetNames = names(loadWorkbook(fil))
     File_data = lapply(sheetNames, function(x){read.xlsx(fil,sheet = x)})
     names(File_data) = sheetNames
     File_data
   })                 But I got a error because of few files. The error was Error in grepl(target, commentsXML) : invalid 'pattern' argument
Called from: grepl(target, commentsXML Any idea why the error oocured?

Comment: Hi Schifini, I observed that the first row in all the sheets in not coming. Can I have that as well?

Comment: Perfect thanks. But I am observing now that all data is getting extracted from Excel but currency like $, Euros etc is not getting extracted. Can we include that as well?

Comment: @Vinay I can't help you without access to your files to see what is the problem. Also, the comments have wandered off the original question and are becoming a free consulting project. I could help you further, but not through SO comments.